# Error in importing android library with Python2.7 on ubuntu

Tags: android, python-2.7

I am getting below error while importing android library in my script.

While I am using

```
import android
```

I am getting following error:

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anoop/Python3.2/android-sdk-linux/mydroidtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import android
ImportError: No module named android
```

Any one please help.
Also at which path I can find android library???
Thanks

Comment: I assume this has something to do with SL4A? If so, read [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/RemoteControl) – you need your phone to host a server and then connect to it with your desktop

Answer (score 0):

Long story short you're going to need to host a server on your phone, forward the appropriate port to your phone with `adb forward` and then you should have full access to the Android module.

For more information head over to the [SL4A wiki](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/RemoteControl)